# Join first elements of a list of strings in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following string that represents a line from a tab delimited txt file:

```
line = 'pf\t2\t0\t9\t0\t9\t9\n'
```

I would like to join the first two elements from this string using an underscore and then write the line back to file. I am using the following simple script to do it:

```
newLabel = '_'.join(line.split('\t')[:2])
newLine = line.split('\t')
newLine[:2] = newLabel
```

What I would expect is the following:

```
['pf_2', '0', '9', '0', '9', '9\n']
```

Instead I am getting:

```
['p', 'f', '_', '2', '0', '9', '0', '9', '9\n']
```

Maybe I am missing something obvious here but why does python split the joined string again? What is the best way to achieve what I want?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were probably looking for a slightly different assignment statement:

```
newLine[:2] = [newLabel]
```

Slice assignment simply expects an iterable on the right hand side.  Since `newLabel`, a string, *was* an iterable, the slice assignment happily goes and iterates it, adding those elements in place of `newLine[:2]`.

You might also consider this shortcut:

```
>>> line.replace('\t', '_', 1)
'pf_2\t0\t9\t0\t9\t9\n'
```

Using the third argument to `str.replace` specifies the number of occurences to replace.

Comment: Is there a simple explanation for the default behaviour of python without the slice assignment?

Comment: Yes, I've added an explanation about the unexpected behaviour you were seeing.

Answer (score 2):

First compute the tokens in `toks`, then rebuild a list using `join` for 2 first items, and the rest of the list for the rest:

```
line = 'pf\t2\t0\t9\t0\t9\t9\n'

toks = line.split('\t')
newLine = ["_".join(toks[:2])]+toks[2:]


print(newLine)
```

result:

```
['pf_2', '0', '9', '0', '9', '9\n']
```